# mapping C# classes to LUA functions using LuaInterface

Tags: c#, lua, integration, luainterface

Is there a way to map classes directly to C# functions by just loading the class? Instead of making 100+ `RegisterFunctions` and mapping them?

EX: Something like

```
this.lua = new LuaInterface.Lua();
RegisterAll(Class1.MainClass);
lua.DoFile(this.filePath);
```

inside lua:

```lua
function Start
    MainClass.MappedPrintFunc("hihi");
end
```

Comment: I don't know LuaInterface. Hence, I think it it physically _possible_, because .NET, unlike C++, has the knowledge of class interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so by setting a variable in LUA to your function that exports funcs or props.

EX:

```
Class Manager()
public static GameLocalPlayer LocalPlayer { get; set; }

LuaInterace lua = new LuaInterface;
lua["variablename"]=Manager.LocalPlayer;  

---lua----
variablename.Health;
variablename:AttackTarget(target);
```